# HTML 5 Offline Application, not working after disconnected internet

Tags: html

How can i create a html 5 page that still works even if internet being disconnected and user press REFRESH (F5) on the browser.

I am referring to this http://html5demos.com/offline page,
it will show Offline when i disconnected my internet, but when i press refresh on browser, it is not working anymore and show page not found.

I want my page to work 100% offline even if user press refresh on browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an 'offline' HTML5 web application, for example by using androids webview, i would suggest using something like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)  this will allow you to create web applications while not necessarily being connected to the internet.  As far as the html5demos go... im not sure what you are trying to get at...
-hope this helps